# Need Help Recovering a File Moved to Incorrect Destination Using 'mv' Command

Tags: command-line

I mistakenly specified the destination directory 'Doc' when using the `mv` command, but there is no such directory. Now, I'm unable to locate my file. How can I find my file that seems to have been moved with an incorrect destination?

```
ahnaf@ahnaf:~/Downloads$ mv 9.xlsx ~/Doc
```

I used the following command to search for the file:

```
find ~/ -type f -name "9.xlsx"
```

Unfortunately, I had no luck finding it. What should I do now? Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file will be called `Doc` in `~` or your home directory.

Your `mv` or move command told it to move the file, and give it a new name, which was done. This may not have been your intention, but it's what you commanded.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution worked perfectly, and I've recovered my file. I appreciate your help and the explanation of what happened.

Comment: FYI:   If your command had been `mv 9.xlsx ~/Doc/` instead (ie. a `/` so the command interpreter knew you wanted to move the file to a directory; you would have received an error that said "*mv: cannot move '9.xlsx' to '~/Doc/': Not a directory*" if no directory called `/Doc` (*directory*) exists within ~  .. ie. you can, by being more specific, reduce your chance of errors but POSIX/unix machines will do what we tell them to.